# Mail merging a 4-up post card in Word for Mac 2008

Tags: macos, office-for-mac, microsoft-word-2008

I need help with mail merging a 4-up postcard I have already created in Word for Mac 2008.

I need one address per card (4 per page), not the same address 4 times per page. Also I need to be able to place the address where I want it. It's not the same place where the mail merge places it. I have both pictures & text already on the postcard & a designated place for the addresses information.